# Ubuntu 19.10 running a Regolith session feels slow

Tags: 19.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 I noticed certain lags and hanging problems which were not present in the 19.04 days. I'm using Regolith as my desktop environment (installed via [its ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kgilmer/+archive/ubuntu/regolith-stable)) and I'm sure that the above problem is happening after upgrading to 19.10 . I have already disabled file indexing.

Comment: And did you follow the precautions listed [here](https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/wiki/HowTo:-Upgrade-to-Ubuntu-19.10-(Eoan-Ermine)) while upgrading?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica i installed Regolith using ppa and did followed the precautions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Ubuntu 19.10 this problem happens due to problem with swap management . Tinkering with dirty_background broke my nautilus file explorer . 
Along with freezing when copying large files , i have encountered several performance issues due to bad swap management in 19.10 . **Since completely disabling swap is not recommended and we can control the degree of writing into swap partition by setting swappiness .**

> swappiness=0 tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of physical memory for as long as possible .
>   swappiness=100 tells the kernel to aggressively swap processes out of physical memory and move them to swap cache

so , we are going to set swappiness =1 .

> To change the swappiness value A temporary change (lost on reboot) with a swappiness value of 1 can be made with

`sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=1`

> To make a change permanent, edit the configuration file with your favorite editor:

`sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

> Search for vm.swappiness and change its value as desired. If vm.swappiness does not exist, add it to the end of the file like so:

`vm.swappiness=10`

> Save the file and reboot.

This helped me to improve overall performance issues in Ubuntu 19.10 while **disabling swap completely eliminated all performance issues that i had with 19.10 but still i won't recommend doing that in normal situations** .